# Fetching data from Solr and load it into a Python Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, solr

I have fetched around 50k rows from Oracle 11g to Solr.

Now i want to fetch the same from Solr to python Dataframe.

I used following:

```
import pandas as pd
import pysolr

r = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/db')

result = r.search('*')  

docs = pd.DataFrame(result.docs)
```

result = r.search('*') #Its throwing an error as SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 504): [Reason: None]504Gateway Timeout

## Gateway Timeout

Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.
Please retry the request or contact your administrator.

I am new to Solr. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=*&wt=json&indent=true`

Answer (score 2):

You get results of type `pysolr.Results`

use functions to get required things like, qtime, docs, facets

`results.docs` give all documents in list, can check using `type(results.docs)`

`results.docs[0]` gives you first document in the results. which is of `dict`type.

To get it into DataFrame import pandas library and use DataFrame()

```
import pandas as pd
import pysolr
solrcon = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/db', timeout=10)
results = solrcon.search('*:*')
docs = pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
```

Comment: results = solrcon.search('*:*') - Throwing an error as "SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 504): [Reason: None]"

Comment: solr instance is running rite.?

Comment: try this on your browser `http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=query_string&indent=on&wt=json` change query_string accordingly and check and what response you get there.

Comment: if you don't get correct JSON response for above URL I mentioned in comment section, something error from solr server.

Comment: yeah, Solr instance is running fine. And I tried json-URL as well on the browser. Its giving correct response.

Comment: strange!, can you send exact error what you getting.

Comment: error - SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 504): [Reason: None]
<html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head><body><h1>Gateway Timeout</h1><p>Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></p></body></html>

I have restarted the server, still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138819/discussion-between-vinod-and-user7276674).

Answer (score 0):

This helps

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from requests.utils import requote_uri
start_num =0
rows_num = 50000
total_docs =7591467
df = pd.DataFrame()
while total_docs> start_num :
    print('start row is',start_num)
    print('row number is ', rows_num)
    time.sleep(2.4)
    url = "localhost:8080/solr/collection_name/select?q=*:*&sort=xyz desc&wt=csv&start={}&rows={}".format(start_num,rows_num)
    encoded_URL = requote_uri(url)
    print(encoded_URL)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(encoded_URL) 
    df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    start_num = start_num+ 50000
```